# How to let simplenews send email instantly without through cron?

Tags: emails

I'm using simplenews and MIME mail in my drupal 7 site to send newsletter.

When I click send newsletter, the sending of newsletter is in pending status and waiting for cron to run and send email.

Is there any method I can send newsletter email directly without waiting for cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using cron (either manually or waiting for it) you could use:

**[Drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/drush/info)**

`drush simplenews-spool-count`

> Print the current simplenews mail spool count

`drush simplenews-spool-send`

> Send the default amount of mails, as defined by the simplenews_throttle variable.

`drush simplenews-spool-send 100`

> Send 100 mails.

`drush simplenews-spool-send 0`

> Send all mails.

**Alternative cronjob usage**

If you can't use drush you can trigger cron manually at `/admin/reports/status/run-cron`, but this will also run all other cronjobs. As an alternative you could install and use [elysia cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) or [ultimate cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) (currently the later looks like to be the more active version). Both modules will allow you to run specific cronjobs manually and separated from others.

Answer (score 0):

You can run cron manually by accessing /admin/reports/status/run-cron in drupal 7

Please have a look at this page https://www.drupal.org/node/369754 which gives more information about newsletters